# How to create route from GPX file with Skobbler?

Tags: objective-c, skmaps

I need to create a route in my mobile app, using the GPX route I received from the server.
I couldn't find any guides on the official skobbler site, nor on the web.

This is what I tried, but failed

```
SKGPSFileElement* gpxFile;
gpxFile.type = SKGPSFileElementGPXRoute;
gpxFile.name = @"route";
gpxFile.extensions = @"gpx";
[[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] calculateRouteWithSettings:nil GPSFileElement:gpxFile];
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest would be to look at the *Tracks* example in the [demo project](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download) as there you already have the code required to read, draw and transform this GPX track to a route.

I think it would go something like this (using the SKGPSFileElement and SKGPSFilesService helper classes):

```
SKGPSFileElement* root = [[SKGPSFilesService sharedInstance] loadFileAtPath:path error:nil];
```

**Note:** if you're just interested in passing the content of the GPX track as an array of points to the routing engine you can use the [calculateRouteWithSettings:customLocations](http://calculateRouteWithSettings:customLocations) API

Comment: Awesome..!! Can we restrict the dragging of map to a certain city ?

Comment: There is a way you can achieve this (limiting panning to a certain bounding box). @RoNit please add a  new question regarding this as I need to provide a lengthier code snippet.